# Cors options to get Gists

Tags: node.js, express, cross-origin-read-blocking

I tried to embed my gist with github script. I have a NodeJS ExpressJS app, create a static page and paste script tag that was generated by github.gist. And now i got an error:

```
my-website:35 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://gist.github.com/PinkyRabbit/7f2db625ae53d799b5ecc4b710c65644 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I tried to allow cors with the [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), but even if I use default setting to open cors for all domains `cors()` - nothing changed, github.gists still blocked.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: As I understand, this corb settings is set by gist service. So embed github gist is possible is only for domains from cors list - not for any like mine. I think the idea is to use gists inside github pages.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and my solution was replacing the initial content of the `iframe` tag

```html
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,
<head>
  <base target='_blank' />
</head>
<body>
  <script src='${this.gist_link}'><\/script>
</body>
```

With:

```html
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,
<head>
  <base target='_blank' />
</head>
<body>
  <script src='${this.gist_link}.js'><\/script>
</body>
```

The difference being the ".js"  at the end of the gist link so github can send the specific resource type that was requested

Answer (score 0):

Gist appears to be supported with CORS on [RawGit](https://raw.githack.com/)

```sh
curl -I https://raw.githack.com/gist/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6/raw/c92df8492be3679635dee0e80273b2ffb6a64cbf/dpy_development_plans.md
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2022 06:56:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=utf-8
...
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

There are a lot of catches though, so read carefully through the link.